# Downloading layer from ArcGIS Online?

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, download, pitem

Can I download a layer from ArcGIS online?

Such as:  the World Urban Areas layer ! I could download the layer with the .pitem extension that opens the layer in ArcGIS desktop when online. But I wanted to download the shapefile to use it offline.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply exported in ArcMap, in the same way as exporting the other layers. Just found it.